# Как передать параметры в запрос через a элемент без url?

Tags: java, html5, jsp

На данный момент я передаю параметры через URL, но мне нужно передавать параметры другим способом с использованием элемента a.

```
    <a href="/controller?command=logout"><fmt:message key="a.exit"/></a>
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.role != 'TEACHER'}">
        <a href="/controller?command=courses"><fmt:message key="a.courses"/></a>
    </c:if>
    <a href="/controller?command=mainPage"><fmt:message key="a.main"/></a>
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.role != 'ADMIN'}">
        <a href="/controller?command=myProfileStudent"><fmt:message key="a.myProfile"/></a>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.role == 'ADMIN'}">
        <a href="/controller?command=newCoursePage"><fmt:message key="a.newCourse"/></a>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.role == 'ADMIN'}">
        <a href="/controller?command=students"><fmt:message key="a.students"/></a>
        <a href="/controller?command=teachers"><fmt:message key="a.teachers"/></a>
    </c:if>
    <div class="changeLanguage">
        <jsp:include page="language.jsp"/>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: другим способом?

Comment: например я могу передавать информацию через форму```<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="newRequirement"/>
                    <button type="submit">${edit}</button></form>``` но мне нужно использовать элемент a

Comment: Можно повесить onClick листенер и отправлять запрос из джаваскрипта. Сам по себе линк отправляет только GET запросы, а у них обычно нет тела.